# ItemContainerGenerator.Items in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, itemcontainergenerator

I started a project using .NET 4.5, now I have to switch to .NET 4.0. Everything works fine, except the "Items"-Property of ItemContainerGenerator is missing. I use it to find the row of a DataGrid that starts with the letter of a typed key.
The Code is:

```
     ReadOnlyCollection<object> rows = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Items;
     datagrid.ScrollIntoView(rows[rows.Count - 1]);
     foreach (DataRowView row in rows)
     {
          string name = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
          if (name.StartsWith(keyChar + "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
               datagrid.ScrollIntoView(row);
               datagrid.UpdateLayout();
               return;
          }
     }
```

Note: When debugging, the "Items"-Property is present and filled.

Do you know a way to access the "Items"-Property or a workaround to get the same function without using the "Items"-Property? Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: I see it even in the 4.0 properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_properties(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing it too complex.
Note: I had to replace ReadonlyCollection<object> by ItemCollection.

Could you post it as answer so I can mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ItemContainerGenerator.Items seems to be present in .NET 4.0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_properties(v=vs.100).aspx

> **.NET Framework 4** Other Versions
>
> ...
>
> **ItemContainerGenerator**    Gets the ItemContainerGenerator that is associated with the control. (Inherited from ItemsControl.)

Comment: The solution was, that DataGrid itself contains the Items-Property that I accessed over ItemContainerGenerator before